# Couldn't find an appropriate operation for XML QName

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've got a .NET 2.0 windows service written by another developer who has since moved on. We don't have the original source code, so I've used JustDecompile to reverse engineer the project back into source code.

When I try to test this web service, it keeps throwing an error:
Couldn't find an appropriate operation for XML QName {my namespace}

The code is decorated with

```
[WebServiceBinding(Name="WFCWebServicesSoapBinding", Namespace="my namespace")]
```

The original code was written in VB.NET; JustDecompile only supports reverse engineering in C#.

I'm kind of confused as to why this is happening - if I've decompiled the app from the code running in my production environment, shouldn't it work the same if I recompile that code?

**EDIT**

Looking at what JustDecompile generated vs. the last known version I have available (this developer created separate versions when changes were made - probably because before me, there was no VM system in place), I don't think there's any way a human being wrote what JustDecompile generated. I think there may be a control character or something throwing off the service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an older version of the code I was working with. It's been tough to decipher exactly what the differences were between them, since JustDecompile about doubled the lines in the code. (And it became an absolute mess - if you use JustDecompile, be aware that the way code is written can have an impact in your decompiled project)

I'm able to run this older code just fine. I think what may be happening is there's a hidden character or something that crashes the web service call.